# how to tag name with value in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am making a simple demo .I am parsing xml .
i want to show `element name and its value` ? ould you please tell how to show 
`element node and its value`
here is my code

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSr/1

**expected out put**

```
name : test
p2 :pppp

name : test2
p2 :eeee

name : testeee2
p2 cccc
```

my code

```
<xsl:template match="firstname" >
        <xsl:for-each select="firstname">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></h1>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: There's a useful tutorial for XSLT at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp. XSLT is very straightforward for this simple requirement and the tutorial will answer this entry level question and inform you about some other aspects that you will come across.

Comment: could you please answer this Question

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you follow the tutorial?

Comment: yes I follow the tutorial that wht I asked this Question please open this link http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSr/1

Comment: @user944513 Please post ALL the necessary code within the question, not in external links.  Also pick either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both.

Comment: You have asked five questions in the last 12 hours, and the questions suggest that you have made no attempt to find out anything about XSLT from books or tutorials. That is an incredibly inefficient learning strategy, which wastes a lot of your time and a lot of time from people who regularly answer questions on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each `student` and select the `firstname` to get your required output.

Demo : - http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSr/3

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="class" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="class" >
        <xsl:for-each select="student">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="firstname" >
      <h1>
        name : <xsl:value-of select="name"/> 
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        p2 : <xsl:value-of select="p2"/>
    </h1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: please see respected output

Comment: @user944513 yes try updated answer and link please. Also you want html output with tags?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="name(p2)"/>` will always return "p2" (unless the node is not there). But hey, why make it simple when it can be complicated?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am learning a lot from your answers everyday. Appreciate. Thanks.